# Entity framework is not adding row in many to many relationship table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database that has  the following tables.

Users:
IdUser

Modules:
IdModule

Many to many relationship causes table UserModule.
IdUser
IdModule

I want to add an already existing module to a user, so the only thing entity framework should do is add a row in UserModule.

But the problem is that it is trying to add a module to the database causing a primary key error.

Here is the code.

```
public static void LoadModuleInUser(string login,Module module) 
        {
                //dbcontext
                using (webentities db= new webentities())
                {
                    User user= db.users.First(u => u.login== login);
                   user.Modules.Add(module);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
        }
```

Comment: show more information about entty mapping

Comment: I created the tables first and then the code, what information do you need?

Comment: so please show me the User entity and Module entity code

Comment: namespace Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class users
    {
        public users()
        {
            this.Modules = new HashSet<Modules>();  
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string login{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Modulos> Modulos { get; set; }
}

Comment: namespace Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Modules
    {
        public Modules()
        {
            users= new HashSet<Users>();
        }
    
        public int IdModulo { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: show me the error message

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. Please show the error. How is module entity being made? Maybe you dont have an auto increment on key somewhere. (I couldnt make comment so i had to post this as answer)

Comment: If i check the user modules list after i add it , everything looks perfect. the problem is when i saveChanges, tries to add module to database not UserModule.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this:

```
User user= db.users.First(u => u.login== login);
user.Modules.Add(module);
db.SaveChanges();
```

to this:

```
User user= db.users.Include("Modules").First(u => u.login== login);
user.Modules.Add(module);
db.SaveChanges();
```